# How To Create a PhoneGap Plugin for BlackBerry WebWorks in eclipse

Tags: cordova, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-webworks

I want to create a custom phonegap plugin for blackberry in eclipse. I dont know how to do it. I have searched over net and i found only one useful link http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/35799737/How%20To%20Create%20a%20PhoneGap%20Plugin%20for%20BlackBerry%20WebWorks and this explains writing your plugin but they are not using Eclipse.
If someone have tried doing it on eclipse. Please help me by guiding the step by step procedure of doing it.

Comment: BlackBerry WebWorks project is not using for creating phonegap project just use this link instruction and run
http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/25653281/Getting%20Started%20with%20PhoneGap-BlackBerry%20with%20the%20Latest%20Environment

Answer (score 0):

There is no full support for cordova plugins with BlackBerry Webworks, but for now you should build a WebWorks extension and import it to the www folder of your PhoneGap project.
You have to create a webworks extension and import it into you cordova project over Blackberry 10 IDE (Momentics).

You can follow this link to get started:

https://github.com/blackberry/WebWorks-Community-APIs/tree/master/BB10/Template

Answer (score -1):

Blackberry web work update site for Eclipse 3.6- http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate/3.6/web